# Disable default behavior on Google maps

Tags: google-maps, default, behavior

guys.

I have the following code in an HTML page. It shows a Google map with custom markers and everithing is working ok so far:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplito</title>
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #CCC;
  }
</style>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
function addMarker(titulo, pos, iconName, mapa) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapa,
    position: pos,
    icon: iconName,
    title: titulo
  });
}
function init(container, x, y, zoom) {        
  map_canvas = document.getElementById(container);
  var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  overviewMapControl: false
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
  addMarkers(map);
}
</script>




<script>
var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var icon = 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Webtoys/64/Pin.png';

function addMarkers(mapa) {
  var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(19.2887395,-99.198382,14);
  addMarker('Primer marcador', pos1, icon, mapa);

  var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(19.2792758,-99.2334069,14);
  addMarker('Segundo pin', pos2, icon, mapa);
}

$(function() {
  init('map_canvas',19.2792608,-99.2334009,13);
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
  <h1>Hola</h1>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

However, when I move the **mouse wheel** over the map, It performs a zoom (out/in) and I need to disable such behavior.

My question is: What code (line, if possible) in my html page should I change/add, in order to disable such behavior?

Than you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in map options:
scrollwheel: false.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ZoomControlOptions